# python requests weird error on PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, python-requests, pythonanywhere

So the following code works perfectly when I run it on my local machine in PyCharm/from shell-script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests
from lxml import etree, html
import chardet

def gimme_pairs():

    url = "https://halbidoncom/sha.xml"
    page = requests.get(url).content
    encoding = chardet.detect(page)['encoding']

    if encoding != 'utf-8':
        page = page.decode(encoding, 'replace').encode('utf-8')

    doc = html.fromstring(page, base_url=url)
    print(doc)
    print(page)
    wanted = doc.xpath('//location')

    print(wanted)

    date_list = None
    tashkif_list = None

    for elem in wanted:
        date_list = elem.xpath('locationdata/timeunitdata/date/text()')
        tashkif_list = elem.xpath('locationdata/timeunitdata/element/elementvalue/text()')
```

But on PythonAnywhere I get this output for `doc`:

> b'\n\n\nChallenge=355121;\nChallengeId=58551073;\nGenericErrorMessageCookies="Cookies
>   must be enabled in order to view  this
>   page.";\n\n\nfunction test(var1)\n{\n\tvar
>   var_str=""+Challenge;\n\tvar var_arr=var_str.split("");\n\tvar
>   LastDig=var
>   _arr.reverse()[0];\n\tvar minDig=var_arr.sort()[0];\n\tvar subvar1 = (2 * (var_arr[2]))+(var_arr[1]*1);\n\tvar subvar2 = (2 * var_arr[2])+v
>   ar_arr[1];\n\tvar
>   my_pow=Math.pow(((var_arr[0]*1)+2),var_arr[1]);\n\tvar
>   x=(var1*3+subvar1)*1;\n\tvar y=Math.cos(Math.PI*subvar2);\n\tvar a
>   nswer=x*y;\n\tanswer-=my_pow*1;\n\tanswer+=(minDig*1)-(LastDig*1);\n\tanswer=answer+subvar2;\n\treturn
>   answer;\n}\n\n\ncli ent = null;\nif
>   (window.XMLHttpRequest)\n{\n\tvar client=new
>   XMLHttpRequest();\n}\nelse\n{\n\tif
>   (window.ActiveXObject)\n\t{\n\t\tclient =  new
>   ActiveXObject(\'MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0\');\n\t};\n}\nif
>   (!((!!client)&&(!!Math.pow)&&(!!Math.cos)&&(!![].sort)&&(!![].reverse)))\n{\n\tdocu
>   ment.write("Not all needed JavaScript methods are
>   supported.
> ");\n\n}\nelse\n{\n\tclient.onreadystatechange  =
>   function()\n\t{\n\t\tif(c lient.readyState  == 4)\n\t\t{\n\t\t\tvar
>   MyCookie=client.getResponseHeader("X-AA-Cookie-Value");\n\t\t\tif
>   ((MyCookie == null) || (MyCooki
>   e==""))\n\t\t\t{\n\t\t\t\tdocument.write(client.responseText);\n\t\t\t\treturn;\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\tvar
>   cookieName = MyCookie.split(\'= \')[0];\n\t\t\tif
>   (document.cookie.indexOf(cookieName)==-1)\n\t\t\t{\n\t\t\t\tdocument.write(GenericErrorMessageCookies);\n\t\t\t\treturn;\
>   n\t\t\t}\n\t\t\twindow.location.reload(true);\n\t\t}\n\t};\n\ty=test(Challenge);\n\tclient.open("POST",window.location,true);\n\tclient.set
>   RequestHeader(\'X-AA-Challenge-ID\',
>   ChallengeId);\n\tclient.setRequestHeader(\'X-AA-Challenge-Result\',y);\n\tclient.setRequestHeader(\'X-
>   AA-Challenge\',Challenge);\n\tclient.setRequestHeader(\'Content-Type\'
>   , \'text/plain\');\n\tclient.send();\n}\n\n\n\
>   nJavaScript must be enabled in order to view this
>   page.\n\n'

Things I've tried:

- Swapping requests for urllib.open()
- Adding headers manually
- ensuring same packages are installed
- upgrading to PA premium account

What gives? what strikes me is that requests is supposed to have the same function on both my machine and theirs.

Comment: This is not the (whole) program you're running.  You've left out the definitions of `html`, `chardet`, `requests`, and who knows what else.  Show us the actual, full, code.

Comment: @JohnGordon done. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the servers you're trying to scrape have protection that tries to make sure you're using a real browser/there's a human behind the request. If you format that response nicely you'll see that it's setting some headers on the page using the `Challenge` and `ChallengeId` at the beginning.

I assume the IPs/servers that PythonAnywhere uses have been added to a list by the server owners to block the requests (maybe someone really spammed them in the past?)

Having a look around for the same headers, I've found this project which seems to have solved the same problem: https://github.com/niryariv/opentaba-server/

They check for the challenge: https://github.com/niryariv/opentaba-server/blob/master/lib/mavat_scrape.py#L31 and parse them with this helper: https://github.com/niryariv/opentaba-server/blob/master/lib/helpers.py#L109

Hope that helps!